# Selecting the 2nd element by using only css

Tags: html, css

Trying to select the 2nd 'column-left' by using only CSS, changing HTML is not an option. :nth-of-type(2) is selecting both of the div's

```html
<div class="collection">

            <div class="column-left"> 
                    
            </div>

            <div class="column-left">

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it won't. `nth-of-type(2)` will select only the second column-left. If it doesn't then you've not posted your full HTML here. There must be some other `div` in between the two column-left (a column-right?).

Comment: Is there any other direct children under div class collection?

Comment: True, that wasn't the complete html.
https://jsfiddle.net/0L1rdLtv/

Answer (score 3):

Use nth-child() selector to get the desired result

change your CSS to this:

```
.column-left:nth-child(2) {
color: red; 
}
```

This link will explain the difference between nth-child selector and nth-of-type:

[Link](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `nth-child(n)` instead of `nth-of-type`

```css
.collection .column-left:nth-child(2) {
    color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">

            <div class="column-left"> 
                123
            </div>

            <div class="column-left">
                456
            </div>
</div>
```